# joomla - forcibly get keyword from specific language

Tags: joomla, localization

I need to use JText in a way that I give it the language I want to be translated. Already tried to set/load that language before calling the JText function, but despite the result of language loading is successful, it always returns the default language's keywords. The site is in Spanish language by default, but there's a component that I need to forcibly get English keywords for it. This is what I tried to do:

```
JText::_("HELLO"); // This returns the Spanish word
JFactory::getLanguage()->load('joomla', JPATH_BASE, 'en-GB, true); // Loading English language
echo JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag();  // This returns en-GB tag!
JText::_("HELLO"); // This returns the Spanish word, too!!!
```

I wish JText class had something like this:

```
JText::_("HELLO", 'en-GB'); // Return English keyword of the specified key
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I've managed to load English language by giving "language" parameter to the URL:

```
http://example.com/index.php?option=com_test&view=test&language=en-GB
```