# joomla - forcibly get keyword from specific language in JText

Tags: php, joomla

actually i was looking for an answer to exact the same problem as in [joomla - forcibly get keyword from specific language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964139), except that his solution would not work for me. here i explain all as good as i can:

i need to use JText in a way that i give it the language i want to be translated. already tried to set/load that language before calling the JText function, but despite the result of language loading is successful, it always returns the default language's keywords. i have wrote a component where a customers request is being sent to the admin via email. the customer gets a copy (in the correct language of the site he is visiting = this is working). the admin though, should get a copy of the same bodytext, but with the forced language:

```
$body = '<td><b>'.JText::_(TPL_FORM_TELEFON).'</b></td><td>'.$_POST['tel'].'</td></tr>'.
```

so that basically `JText::_(TPL_FORM_TELEFON)` is in the copy email sent to the customer either `en-GB` or `ru-RU` (depending what language he is visiting) but for the admin `JText::_(TPL_FORM_TELEFON)` HAS to be in german (`de-DE`)

any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this. Find this article inside the Joomla! Docs: https://docs.joomla.org/Specification_of_language_files

Right at the end under the heading "**Loading any language file, anywhere**" there is a way shown to load arbitrary front-end and back-end language files. The important information is that

> untranslated strings will appear in English and not as untranslated keys

This way you can load front-end translated strings for the email send to the customer, and for the admin you can load the german back-end language file. As long as you don't translate the german back-end language file and let the en & ru empty, you should always get the german strings for the admin email. Bare in mind that you might need to use different language keys for the back-end and front-end language files in order for this to work.

**Example front-end keys:**
for de-DE: `TPL-FROM-TELEFON="Telefon"`
for en-GB: `TPL-FROM-TELEFON="Phone"`

**Example back-end keys:**
for de-DE: `TPL-FROM-TELEFON-ADMIN="Telefon"`
for en-GB: `TPL-FROM-TELEFON-ADMIN` **= DO NOT INCLUDE THIS KEY AT ALL!!!**

At the end you need to load the language files like explained inside the Joomla! Docs:

You can use something like this for the back-end language files:

```
$language = JFactory::getLanguage();
$language->load('com_yourcomponentname', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR, 'en-GB', true);
$language->load('com_yourcomponentname', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR, null, true);
```

And to load the front-end language files, using the same trick:

```
$language = JFactory::getLanguage();
$language->load('com_yourcomponentname', JPATH_SITE, 'en-GB', true);
$language->load('com_yourcomponentname', JPATH_SITE, null, true);
```